# How to set a certain country as default in guest from and not select another one

Tags: magento-1.9, countries, guest-checkout

i would like to set the country in guest checkout form for invoice und delivery adress hardcoded to default country x. And no other country should be able to getting selected.
How do i managed this?
Thanks already for support
Greetz

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest method to achieve this is to override `billing.phtml` and `shipping.phtml` in your custom module and then replace country select field with your single country dropdown for guest users.

```
<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
<select > 
    <option>Select Country</option> 
    <option selected="selected" name="YOUR_COUNTRY_VALUE" >YOUR_COUNTRY_NAME</option> 
</select>
<?php else: ?>
DEFAULT DROPDOWN CODE
<?php endif; ?>
```